# How can I optimize this menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr5Vf/11/) !

I am trying to make user page where he can switch between pages by clicking on div's. Problem is, I will need more then 3 div's , and this already is very messy...

```
<div id="dviOverdivWraper">
    <div class="containterBox">
        <div id="leftOver" style="background-color:blue">
        </div>
        <div id="rightOver" style="background-color:red">
        </div>
        <div id="thirdOver" style="background-color:yellow">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#dviOverdivWraper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    top: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
#dviOverdivWraper .containerBox{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#leftOver{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#rightOver, #thirdOver{
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

```js
$("#rightOver").click(function () {
    $("#leftOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#rightOver").animate({
        width: "400px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#thirdOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
});
$("#leftOver").click(function () {
    $("#rightOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#leftOver").animate({
        width: "400px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#thirdOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
});
$("#thirdOver").click(function () {
    $("#rightOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#leftOver").animate({
        width: "50px"
    }, 500, null);
    $("#thirdOver").animate({
        width: "400px"
    }, 500, null);
});
```

How can I optimize it, because I will need more then 3 div's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KECJH/1/)*

```
    // SET MIN WIDTH:
    var minW = 50;
    // SET MAX WIDTH:
    var maxW = 400;
    // SET INITIALLY OPENED BOX:
    var openBox = 1;
    // SET ANIMATION SPEED (in milliseconds)
    var speed = 400;
    //////////////////////
      
$('.box').eq(openBox-1).width(maxW).siblings().width(minW); // initial setup

function animate(){
   $('.box').eq(openBox).stop().animate({width: maxW},speed).siblings().animate({width: minW},speed);            
}
    
$('.box').on('click', function(){
   openBox = $(this).index();
   animate();                    
});
```

P.S: I just added a class `.box` to your elements.

Comment: If you want to wait till an animation ended before any triggering is possible - change inside the animation function this: `$('.box:not(:animated)')`

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="over"` to each of the three sections and then you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dviOverdivWraper .over").click(function() {
        if ($(this).width() == 50) {
            $("#dviOverdivWraper .over").not(this).animate({width: "50px"}, 500);
            $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 500);
        }
    });
});​
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5UbQM/.

The follows the DRY principles of not repeating code and it automatically supports however many sections you have without changing the code at all.

Comment: Why did someone downvote?  This is nice compact code that supports an arbitrary number of sections.  It follows the DRY principles of not repeating code and that also makes it compact.  Downvoters - do you realize that your votes accomplish little if you don't explain why you thought the answer was inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. You can [try it out in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr5Vf/10/). It requires no changes to your HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".containterBox > div").click(function() {
       $(".containterBox > div").not(this).animate({
            width: "50px"
        }, 500, null);
       $(this).animate({
            width: "400px"
        }, 500, null);             
    });
});​​​
```

Comment: This wont be good, because I will have more divs inside these ones.

Comment: @skmasq: You could use `$(".containerBox > div")` as the selector instead.

Comment: @Whymarrh That would definitely be an improvement. I've added it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using horizontal accordion, like the one here:

http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/

or here

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion-horizontal.html

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="myitem"` to your divs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myitem").first().animate({width:"400"});
    $(".myitem").not(":first").animate({width:"50"})
    $(".myitem").on("click",function(){
        $(".myitem").not(this).animate({width:"50"})    
        $(this).animate({width:"400"});                   
    });
});​
```

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9AzF/3/).